# Ruby version mismatch when deploying war over tomcat

Tags: ruby, tomcat, jruby, rvm, warbler

I am using Rvm and have install jruby-1.6.4 (with ruby 1.9.2) 
i use warbler to create the war file and deploy it over tomcat-6.0.4

the problem is while i run the application the tomcat logs shows ruby version used as 1.8.7

I checked the version of ruby thru rvm list and it shows the right version (1.8.7)

When i downgrade teh jruby to use 1.8.7 (by using JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8.7 the application works like charm

any idea on how to ensure that ruby version 1.9.2 is used by tomcat

Vivek

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the Java property `jruby.compat.version` to `1.9` in Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

Inside warble.rb (created when/if you call >warble config)

```
Warbler::Config.new do |config|
# stuff before
   config.webxml.jruby.compat.version = "1.9"
# stuff after
end
```

This config (and a lot more) will actually already be present, yet commented out when the warble.rb file is generated.

http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/